# JSON_EXTRACT always returning null in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

Hi I'm new to SP and JSON function in mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `adocs_sp_web_questionnaire_has_child`(IN 
`var_has_child_text` TEXT, IN `var_parent_id` INT, OUT `var_child_text` TEXT)
BEGIN 

DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE count_max INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE individual_question,question_child,question_name,questions_list, json VARCHAR(255); 
DECLARE i,var_parent_id_output INT DEFAULT 0; 

SELECT var_has_child_text INTO json; 

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json,"$.child_list")  AS questions_list;
END
```

var_has_child_text is a input parameter with the below JSON value and var_parent_id is 5

```
{"child_list":[{"name": "Sub Question 1", "has_child": [{"name": "Sub Question 1 1", 
"has_child": [{"name": "Sub Question 1 1 1"}, {"name": "Sub Question 1 1 2"}, {"name": "Sub 
Question 1 1 3"}]}, {"name": "Sub Question 1 2"}, {"name": "Sub Question 1 3"}]}, {"name": 
"Sub Question 2"}, {"name": "Sub Question 3"}]}
```

I'm trying to extract the above var_has_child_text (JSON) with

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json,"$.child_list") AS questions_list;
```

But it always returns null ;

But I need to split this JSON array of object based on the key "child_list" into individual iteration and based on the value I need to perform the other stuffs.

TIA.

Detailed Video Requirement :

https://www.loom.com/share/c6042f43967044689e50169fb75d67cb

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid. Remove all linebreaks from it.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(var_has_child_text, '\r', ' '), '\n', ' ') INTO json;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebe1eae6e351cb76da27618f48470a21

PS. JSON allows inner linebreaks but out of the values only. I.e. the linebreak between your rows 2 and 3 is not legal whereas linebreaks between rows 1 and 2 and between rows 3 and 4 are legal.

PPS. Of course this method may add excess spaces into the values. But this method is a palliative - you must fix the code which creates source JSON and avoid linebreaks in the value.